# naudio 32bit ieee float to 24bit

Tags: stream, naudio, ieee, 24-bit

In NAudio I need to play a WAV file with an ASIO driver that only accepts 24bit audio.
The wave stream is stored in a wav file, but it is 32bit ieee float.
I need to convert the stream from 32bit to 24bit.
I tried all the NAudio conversion functions but no one is good for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

ASIO has a bunch of different ways it can receive 24 bit audio (big endian or little endian, 3 bytes or 4 bytes per sample), and NAudio doesn't have converters for all of them. The [`AsioSampleConverter`](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudio/Wave/Asio/ASIOSampleConvertor.cs) class contains converters for the most commonly used formats, so you possibly adapt one of the built in converters to your use case.